# Python + Selenium : Finding text in multiple spans with no element identifiers

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to retrieve the value "Condo Apt" corresponding to "Type" and the value "Apartment" corresponding to "Levels. However because there are no tags for me to search by, I was wondering how can I retrieve the values I am looking for?

Example link: https://www.zoocasa.com/toronto-on-real-estate/418-199-richmond-st-w

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML structure remains consistent on the website, you can use XPATH.

On inspect element highlight the  right click and select Xpath - Copy Full Xpath

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get('https://www.zoocasa.com/toronto-on-real-estate/418-199-richmond-st-w')
testvar = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/section/section/div[1]/span[2]')
print(testvar.text)
```

This prints out Condo Apt for the webpage you provided.

Comment: What if the HTML structure varies? This assumes the structure stays the same.

Comment: This code works with other condos from that web page, so the structure remains the same. If the website changes their structure which should not be often, you would need to update the xpath. Otherwise you would probably need to implement some machine learning or regex to have the program find it by itself.